# Differential load a file into database

Tags: java, database

I am looking for a solution of following problem in java or database. Please help.

We have to read a file and put the records in oracle database. File is like a csv format (column values are with pipe | separated) at a FTP location. Let's say file name is employee.txt and corresponding table name is Employee. Asuming the columns as -

```
ID
name
Designation
Date_of_Joining
```

Records in txt file will be as -

```
1234|saurabh srivastava|lead|06-0ct-1990
1235|a john|lead|09-nov-1992
1236|p kumar||10-dec-1991
```

The file will always contain full records. Means, if first time file has 10 records, next time it will have these 10 records along with the new records. But everytime we need to store new records only in the database. Is there any way using java program or in Databse (Procedure, query etc.), cosidering less performance hit.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the new records always at the end of the file or can they be mixed in at various positions.

Comment: Creating file is actually an export from database. Not sure how it will put the records each time.

Comment: Worth testing but I'd guess it would be in primary key order, so if your key is an auto incrementing field it would always have the newest on the bottom. Then another problem might be if a record gets modified from one version of the text to another. It would suck but you might have to truncate the table and restore from the text file to be sure you got everything to the state it was in at the time of the backup.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be a mixed approach. Assuming nothing else modifies the file you could  store in the database the last line read. Then your java program can open up the file, get the last line from the database (or another file with the last read line number) skip to the next row (assuming it exists) and just start parsing/inserting the values into the database. I don't think the database only approach will be great for you as you'd be putting all the parsing processing, assuming it is even possible, onto your server instead of being able to decouple it off onto a client or another "log" server for that part.

Either way you need to persist the last line read somehow otherwise you'll end up having to process the whole file every time and then just insert whatever isn't there which both wouldn't be efficient and would take longer and longer over time.

Comment: Bad news :(. It is not necessary that new records will be at the end of file.
Following structure is possible:
File1:
Record A
Record B
Record C
File 2:
Record A,
Record C
Record D
So, file 2 may not have record B at all, may be a employee is no longer available etc.

Comment: If this is the case, we have to rely on key combination and a high level design would be something like this –
1. We will maintain two tables –
a. Employee and Employee_tmp
2. Read file and store everything in Employee_tmp
3. If Employee table is empty then copy all records from Employee_tmp to Employee table
4. Clean Employee_tmp table
5. Next iteration
6. Read file and store everything in Employee_tmp
7. If row count in Employee_tmp table is greater than zero then

Comment: start matching the records as below [Still have to analyze if we need to write a program in java or database a query can do the same] –
a. Select key [Employee ID)] from Employee_tmp table 
b. Check if they are already in Employee table. If yes, skip to the next record else insert the record.
Please suggest.